# non www doesn't work, 301 doesn't redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, cname

I just got a VPS and uploaded wordpress but non wwww's are not working. I tried to add this to .htaccess but it doesn't work again.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

also tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, I have some backlinks to domain.com but the this doesn't work. Is there a something to change on domain cPanel, such as CNAME or something else?

Comment: So the above rules didn't redirect you to `www.`? Or you got any error?

Comment: Hi, I got error, it says "This web page is not available, ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this and it works just fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^expirio\.sk
RewriteRule (.*) http://expirio.sk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

UPDATE1: But this is obviously to redirect the user from non expirio.sk (e.g. www.expirio.sk) to non www version of expirio.sk. If you want it the other way around then you would want to use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^expirio\.sk
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.expirio.sk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Check the rules here:

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

UPDATE2: Regarding the DNS settings I use just A records to point `expirio.sk` to a specific IP address and also `*.expirio.sk` to point to the same IP address. No CNAME records.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I got this error everytime: ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED

Comment: Ok then it seems your DNS server is not configured correctly to accept the domain that`s not working for you like i described - A records possibly. Can you check that both wildcard and non wildcard versions are configured like i described?

Comment: I couldn't add the code to my comment, sorry, that's why I answered again.

Answer (score 0):

this is the configuration:

```
212.58.8.110 / 24   PTR domain.com.
    domain.com. NS  ns.domain.com.
    domain.com. A   212.58.8.110
    domain.com. MX (10) mail.domain.com.
    domain.com. TXT v=spf1 +a +mx -all
    ftp.domain.com. CNAME   domain.com.
    mail.domain.com.    A   212.58.8.110
    ns.domain.com.  A   212.58.8.110
    webmail.domain.com. A   212.58.8.110
    www.domain.com. CNAME   domain.com.
10 DNS records total
```

Comment: @mareksuscak  I couldn't add the code to my comment, sorry, that's why I answered again.

Comment: Did you configure the DNS records yourself? Or is it auto configured by the provider? Which entries have you configured?

Comment: What is the target domain. I can check it.

Comment: It was auto configured. Now I just changed the DNS zone from www.domain.com to domain.com. Because when I write www.www.domain.com it still opens the site. I thought that may be I had to remove www from DNS zone. Now the site doesn't work :( I will wait a couple hour, maybe it works :(

Comment: target domain is frandayaz.com

Comment: Try to flush the DNS cache on your machine. Also renewing DNS entries takes preconfigured number of seconds known as TTL value in you DNS configuration.

Comment: Btw are you sure of the domain name you mentioned? This domain and none of the other combinations do work. You must have misspelled it.

Comment: Sorry about that; the target domain is fransadayaz.com (212.58.8.110). But it doesn't work after I changed the DNS zone from www.fransadayaz.com to fransadayaz.com. Thank you so much for your help mareksuscak.

Comment: I reversed the change which I done (changing dns zone from wwww.domain.com to domain.com). Cause it wasn't working at all. But after I reversed the change, it still doesn't work; I mean, the site completely gone :(

Comment: You have to wait a few minutes for Time To Live to pass. Then it'll work again. Seems to me that DNS is correct though. Maybe those cname records cause trouble. My provider does not use CNAME at all because it has some side effects. It requires more investigation step by step.

Comment: I would suggest to contact your provider with the request as they have the permissions to play with the configuration. And they surely know what they are doing. DNS configuration is not that easy thing to master.